# SSRS Create an expression which translates text to existing variable

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, expression

I have MDX query to SSAS which generates a dataset with columns like:

- UK_Price
- FR_Price
- IT_Price
- ...

Is it possible to run the Expression like the below to get dynamically the value for the specified column based on the chosen parameter?

```
="Fields!"& Parameters!Country.Label & "_Price.Value"
```

I'm doing right now if-else Expression but anytime where there is a price for a new country, I need to remember to add the new if-else statement.

Comment: Did you try that? What was the result? Why can't you use the SSAS dataset as your parameter list? Or I must be missing something here. You could also in that dataset, create a column to take the first 2 characters for your `Country`. If it's always 2 characters.

Comment: Yes, I tried. And the result is just plain text ("Fields!UK_Price.Value").
I don't understand what exactly you mean by 'dataset as parameter list' - can you please give an example?
And adding a column won't solve the problem since UK_Price, FR_Price are column names, not values in a column.

Comment: Oh. Ok, I thought the values were `UK_Price`, etc. I didn't realize that they were the column names. I think you'd be better off sending the country value chosen to a dynamic stored procedure.

Comment: I tried using the `StrToMember`/`StrToSet` but it's a little bit complicated to do this in my MDX query. Now I am trying to use T-SQL with executing `openrowset` to my cube but I have problems with multiple values in another parameter ;) That's why the exact solution for my question would save me a lot of time.